# Visual Studio 2015 loops on WPF application creation

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've a weird problem with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise...when I create a new WPF project (I've tried web , console and winapps it works) I got the IDE to loop on this message ... The strange thing is if I create a Telerik WPF application the IDE doen't loop and I can start to work on it

[image]

I've uninstalled VS a lot of times...tried to reaload defaul settings... is there a way I can spot what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Probgably a bug, so you should probably report it to Microsoft, as there's probably nothing we can do seeing the project hasn't even been created.

Comment: I have the same issue when I create c++ win32 project